# Сортировка массива структур по нескольким полям

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка, инспекция-кода

Решил задачу, вопрос на которую ранее сам задавал, хочу поделиться.

Задача: есть структура. У структуры три поля: фамилия (char) , имя(char), год рождения (int).

Массив таких структур нужно отсортировать по каждому полю. Т.е. сначала все элементы сортируем по фамилии, затем их сортируем по имени, и потом по году. 
Сначала у нас идут все элементы с фамилией на А, именем на А и минимальным годом рождения среди тех у кого фамилия и имя на А... затем все с фамилией на В, именем на В и минимальным годом рождением среди тех у кого имя и фамилия на В... Это общий принцип.

Массив структур автомобилей:

```
struct Car
{
    int idCar = 0; //порядковый номер элемента массива структур (id) 
    int size = 0; //размер элемента структур
    char regNum[7]; //поле с регистрационным номером
    char markCar[10];//марка автомобиля
    char modelCar[10]; //модель автомобиля
    int mileAge = 0; //пробег автомобиля
    int isEmpty = 0; //индикатор, если поля марка, модель, рег. номер и пробег пустые, то  == 0
};
```

Функция по расширению, добавлению нового элемента в конец массива структур:

```
void addCar(Car *cars)
{

    int N = cars->size;
    N += 1;
    int id = N - 1;
    *cars = *(Car*)realloc(cars, (N+1) * sizeof(Car));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        (cars+i)->size = N;
    }
    (cars + id)->idCar = id;
    (cars + id)->isEmpty = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) (cars + id)->markCar[i] = '\0';
    (cars + id)->mileAge = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<7; i++)(cars + id)->regNum[i] = '\0';
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++) (cars + id)->modelCar[j] = '\0';
}
```

Функция по поиску структурированной переменной с наименьшим значением поля пробег:

```
void minMileAge(Car *cars)
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < cars->size; i++)
    {
        if (min > (cars + i)->mileAge) min = (cars + i)->mileAge;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < cars->size; j++)
    {
        if (min == (cars + j)->mileAge && (cars + j)->mileAge != 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", (cars + j)->idCar);
            printf("Регистрационный номер: %s\n", (cars + j)->regNum);
            printf("Марка автомобиля: %s\n", (cars + j)->markCar);
            printf("Пробег автомобиля: %d\n", (cars + j)->mileAge);
        }
    }
}
```

Функции для сравнения структурированных переменных типа Car:

```
int my_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    for (; *s1 != '\0' && *s2 != '\0' && (*s1 == *s2); s1++, s2++);
    return *s1 - *s2;
}
int cmpCar(Car *t1, Car *t2)
{
    int result;
    if ((result = my_strcmp(t1->markCar, t2->markCar))) return result;
    if((result = my_strcmp(t1->modelCar, t2->modelCar))) return result;
    if (result = (t1->mileAge - t2->mileAge)) return result;
    return my_strcmp(t1->regNum, t2->regNum);
}
```

Функция сортировки массива структур типа Car по 4 полям (методом вставок):

```
void sortCar(Car *cars)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < cars->size; ++i)
    {
        Car x = *(cars+i);
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && cmpCar((cars + j - 1), &x)>0)
        {
            *(cars+j) = *(cars + j - 1);
            j = j - 1;
        }
        *(cars + j) = x;
    }
    for(int l = 0; l<cars->size; l++)
    {
        printf("ID номер автомобиля %d\n", (cars + l)->idCar);
        printf("Марка автомобиля: %s\n", (cars + l)->markCar);
        printf("Модель автомобиля: %s\n", (cars + l)->modelCar);
        printf("Пробег автомобиля: %d\n", (cars + l)->mileAge);
        printf("Регистрационный номер: %s\n", (cars + l)->regNum);
    }
}
```

И функция поиска элемента из массива структур, по полю,  содержащему искомую подстроку:

```
void allCar(Car *cars)
{
    int result;
    char sbm[10];
    printf("%s", "Введите значение для поиска: ");
    scanf("%s", &sbm);
    for (int i = 0; i < cars->size; i++)
    {
        if ((strstr((cars + i)->markCar, sbm)!=NULL || (strstr((cars + i)->modelCar, sbm))!=NULL || (strstr((cars + i)->regNum, sbm)!=NULL)))
        {
            printf("id автомобилей содержащих значение %d\n", (cars + i)->idCar);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Igor, даже с ней вполне нормально. Он расписал, что нужно сделать (отсортировать по трём полям), как он пытается это сделать (через три сортировки) и что именно у него не получается (выделить подмассивы, которые надо сортировать второй и третьей сортировками). Неужели для ответа на вопрос действительно нужна стена кода с этими попытками? В вопросе и так всё есть. И фраза, что нужно именно на си (а не на плюсах, например), вопросу в общем-то не вредит.

Comment: Перед выписыванием закрывашки по новомодной причине "содержит только текст задания" призываю [ознакомиться на Мете с мотивами для введения этой причины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Реализация на C  - обычный `qsort`, только функция сравнения должна быть немного сложнее, только и всего. Для типа наподобие

```
typedef struct Person {
    char f[20];
    char n[20];
    int y;
} Person;
```

имеем

```
int comp(const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2)
{
    Person * p1 = (const Person*)ptr1;
    Person * p2 = (const Person*)ptr2;

    int cmp = strcmp(p1->f, p2->f);
    if (cmp) return cmp;

    int cmp = strcmp(p1->n, p2->n);
    if (cmp) return cmp;

    return p1->y - p2->y;
}
```

Примерно так. Писал "на коленке", не комппилируя - просто показать принцип. Сравниваете по первому полю, при равенстве - по второму, при равенстве - по третьему.

И никаких трех сортировок...

Comment: О, а вот и компаратор подъехал, пока я писал :) А то мне не хотелось его писать)))

Comment: Кстати, на плюсах при помощи stable_sort можно было бы и 3 сортировки навесить. Только в другом порядке.

Comment: @Qwertiy И называлось бы это, к вящему изумлению ТС, поразрядной сортировкой :)

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что это так называется, но, определённо, логика одинаковая :)

Comment: я ниже на свой вопрос ответил, дал доп. комментарии. Не могли бы вы взглянуть и дать свое профессиональное суждение?

Answer (score 2):

> Понятно, что нужно три функции, одна всех отсортирует по фамилии, вторая отсортирует всех по фимени и третья всех по году.

Нет. Нужна одна функция, которая сортирует сразу по всему.

> Как реализовать сами функции сортировки понятно, а как задать последующие границы сортировки по остальным полям?

В Си есть функция [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), позволяющая сортировать массив переданным компаратором. Подроблнее про компараторы (правда, на javascript) можно почитать в [этом ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988). Только отмечу, что вариант с `||` в си работать не будет, так что надо писать полностью.

Компаратор есть в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/722992/178988)  @Harry.

---

Кстати, если бы надо было воспользоваться именно тремя сортировками, то надо было бы, во-первых, использовать функцию [стабильной сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (в си++ есть stable_sort, в си, вроде, ничего нет), а во-вторых, применять сортировки в порядке, обратном желаемому: сначала отсортировать всё по году, потом всё по имени (с равными именами останутся упорядоченными по году), а потом по фамилии (с равными фамилиями останутся урпорядоченными по имени и году).

Comment: Я ниже сам ответил на свой вопрос, дал доп. комментарии к своему вопросу. Не могли бы вы взглянуть?

Comment: @SergeyZinovev, перечитай первый и последний абзацы.